# Area bounded by 3 curves

Tags: integration

I am currently trying to find the area bounded by the equations $3y-x=6$, $x+y=-2$ and $x+y^2=4$ (no specific assumptions aside from $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$). Plotting the graph, we can see that:

[image]

My math professor asserts that the only accepted region bounded by the curve is:
["correct" area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGNgl.png)

The reason for this is that only this region is the one bounded by both the curves $y=\sqrt{4-x}$ and $y=-\sqrt{4-x}$ (basically the parabola given in the question in terms of $y$). However, given the wording of the question, shouldn't the region be: [my curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1CBh.png)?

I cannot fathom the reason why we should make additional assumptions that it must be bounded by both halves of the curves $x + y^2 = 4$. Even if we were to break the curve into two halves, I would say we should find the union of all regions that are bounded by $x + y^2 = 4$ with the other two lines, not just a single region where it is bounded by the two lines and both halves of the curve $x + y^2 = 4$.

Can someone here guide me on what the proper region should be? I don't wish to be misled by the requirements of my institution.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are fine in your assumption, if the question instead had $\geq$ and $\leq$ signs then any one of the three regions you combined to create your larger region can be singled out (but this is not the case so your assumption is fine).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Is this a high school thing? I'd be shocked if a university professor is this insistent on a vague definition. As for @JeanMarie, replying to your comment, aren't many of these 8 regions nonempty? In fact, three of them are finite.

Comment: @Benjamin Wang I was wrong (I have deleted my comment). You are perfectly right about the $7=2^3-1$ regions delimited by the curves, the 3 ones which are "bounded" (I wouldn't use the term "finite") are "eligible" (but I discard their union as being an answer)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. By "finite" I meant "finite area".

Comment: @BenjaminWang Thanks for the welcome. This is in fact a question at university. I've thought about this long and hard, and I just cannot agree to the region given as the answer due to the lack of any additional restrictions beyond $x$ and $y$ being real numbers.